# TypeError: non-boolean (Num) used in boolean context with symbolic Julia, How to fix?

Tags: julia

Opened an issue as suggested.  https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl/issues/718

---

I wanted to translate this

[image]

To Julia. So Installed symbolics, defined `x` but get an error. The following is the code

```
>julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.7.3 (2022-05-06)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  
|__/                   |

julia> using Symbolics

julia> @variables x
1-element Vector{Num}:
 x

julia> sqrt(-im+x)
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (Num) used in boolean context
Stacktrace:
 [1] sqrt(z::Complex{Num})
   @ Base ./complex.jl:501
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1

julia>
```

Noticed that `im+x` works. But `sqrt(im+x)` gives the error.

What is the problem and is there a workaround?

Comment: you should probably open an issue to https://github.com/JuliaSymbolics/Symbolics.jl/

Comment: Probably related to [this FAQ](https://symbolics.juliasymbolics.org/stable/manual/faq/#Transforming-my-function-to-a-symbolic-equation-has-failed.-What-do-I-do?-1), but I don't understand the details enough to know why `sqrt(::Complex)` is "an algorithm which cannot be traced into a purely symbolic algorithm", or which function you should `@register_symbolic` here to get your expected output.

Comment: Weird issue, but if you replace `@variables x` with `@syms x` then it works fine

Comment: @BallpointBen That is good workaround. If you post it as answer will accept it.